# How to use LinkedIn api with Node js

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

All I need is to check in the backend side if the user access token is valid and get user email by its access token. It's hard to understand how to use this [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin-v2)  for these purposes, so please help me.
In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#retrieving-member-email-address) I've found the API address for it, but how to fetch the with Client ID and  Client Secret of my app which I created on https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/new..
Hopefully, my question makes sense, thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;

// linkedin app settings
var LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID_HERE";
var LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE";
var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')(LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID, LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    clientID: LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/linkedin/callback",
    scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile', 'rw_company_admin'],
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    req.session.accessToken = accessToken;
    process.nextTick(function () {
        return done(null, profile);
    });
}));

// for auth

app.get('/auth/linkedin',
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', { state: 'SOME STATE'  }),
  function(req, res){
    // The request will be redirected to LinkedIn for authentication, so this
    // function will not be called.
});

// for callback

app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

This is a Code Snippet of how i have used it, i guess it will help you on fetching with CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET.

Note : npm passport and passport-linkedin-oauth2 should already be installed

Comment: May I know why do you need `var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')(LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID, LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET);
`  as it is not used in your code sample ?

Comment: var Linkedin = ('node-linkedin') is another library, this library was made because Linkedin API  was sometimes not compatible with OAuth2.0

Comment: Why is it in your snippet if it's not used and not relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```
const accessToken = req.params.accessToken;
const options = {
    host: 'api.linkedin.com',
    path: '/v2/me',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
    }
};

const profileRequest = https.request(options, function(result) {
    let data = '';
    result.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
        console.log(data)
    });

    result.on('end', () => {
        const profileData = JSON.parse(data);
        return res.status(200).json({
            'status': true,
            'message': "Success",
            'result': profileData
        });
    });
});
profileRequest.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing NodeJS LinkedIn official API is not so straightforward and hardly maintained.
If relevant, you can use this [NodeJS LinkedInAPI.](https://github.com/eilonmore/linkedin-private-api)

It allows you to easily login via username & password or with a Cookie and make various requests:

```js
import { Client } from 'linkedin-private-api';

const username = process.env.USERNAME as string;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD as string;

(async () => {
  // Login
  const client = new Client();
  await client.login.userPass({ username, password });
  
  // search for companies
  const companiesScroller = await client.search.searchCompanies({ keywords: 'Microsoft' });
  const [{ company: microsoft }] = await companiesScroller.scrollNext();

  // Search for profiles and send an invitation
  const peopleScroller = await client.search.searchPeople({
    keywords: 'Bill Gates',
    filters: {
      pastCompany: microsoft.companyId
    }
  });
  const [{ profile: billGates }] = await peopleScroller.scrollNext();
  
  await client.invitation.sendInvitation({
    profileId: billGates.profileId,
    trackingId: billGates.trackingId,
  });
})
```